# Delphi:Get data from DDE server

Tags: delphi, dde

I have somethin like that:

```
function DDE_Read(Service, Topic, Items: string): string;
var
  DDE: TDDEClientConv;
begin
  try
    DDE := TDDEClientConv.Create(nil);
    DDE.SetLink(Service, Topic);
    DDE.OpenLink;
    Result:=DDE.RequestData(Items);
  finally
    DDE.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I connect to DDE server and get data. Sometimes I can get data and sometimes I receive empty string. Can you tell me is this code ok? How often I can connect to dde server to get data?

Have you maybe some *dll or your own code?

//EDIT
Im beginer and I dont now always what you mean :) I am very grateful that you're helping me. So my code should be smth like that?

```
function DDE_Read(Service, Topic, Items: string): string;
var
DDE: TDDEClientConv;
temp:PAnsiCHar;
begin
DDE := TDDEClientConv.Create(nil);
DDE.SetLink(Service, Topic);
DDE.OpenLink;
try
temp:=DDE.RequestData(Items);
Result:=temp;
SysUtils.StrDispose(temp);
finally
DDE.Free;
end;
end;
```

Comment: You forgot `StrDispose` to prevent memory leaks -> [`TDdeClientConv.RequestData`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DdeMan.TDdeClientConv.RequestData)

Comment: It's `RequestData(Items)` that you're supposed to dispose of, don't use StrNew. Anyway, AFAICT that comment was not meant to provide a solution to your problem, it just noted a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, StrNew and StrDispose are dinosaurs. Don't use them unless you are from the 20th Century and using a time machine to post now. To address your problem I suggest that you offer us an SSCCE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: isn't DDE _from_ the 20th century? I would advise to check if the application has a COM object or OLE automation or ActiveX interface.

Comment: Your try/finally is wrong. The resource acquisition comes before the try.

Comment: Not related with your problem but the code in your last edit still leaks memory. You're disposing the string you allocated: temp. I repeat, remove 'StrNew'.

Comment: To increase any chance of a solution, refer to David's comment.

Comment: Why do you ask for help and then ignore advice? What will motivate us to help you?

Comment: @user - Yes, that should take care of the leak.

Comment: Have you maybe some ideas? Because I have still my problem :(

Comment: @user - Add a call to `DdeGetLastError(ddeMgr.DdeInstId)` for when the response is empty. Let's see if it returns a useful DMLERR. Use 'ddeml'.

Comment: When response is empty DdeGetLastError(ddeMgr.DdeInstId) returns '0'.

Comment: 0 is DMLERR_NO_ERROR. So it's not that the server is busy or anything...

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, there are sometimes problems using DDE when a lot of connections are opened and closed in a short time interval. I'm unsure if this is still a problem with modern Windows systems. On the other hand, the pure need for you to use DDE suggests that you are not working in a modern environment.

You can try to keep the TDDEClientConv instance for a specific Service or a combination of Service and Topic alive for a longer time. This might at least reduce your problem.